# Getting the pseudo elemente :before/:after working in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to get these to work in IE 7 but I am having problems. I downloaded and included the jQuery plugin for it in the header like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.pseudo.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

But it's still not working.

Here is the code from the jQuery plugin..

```
(function($){

    var patterns = {
        text: /^['"]?(.+?)["']?$/,
        url: /^url\(["']?(.+?)['"]?\)$/
    };

    function clean(content) {
        if(content && content.length) {
            var text = content.match(patterns.text)[1],
                url = text.match(patterns.url);
            return url ? '<img src="' + url[1] + '" />': text;
        }
    }

    function inject(prop, elem, content) {
        if(prop != 'after') prop = 'before';
        if(content = clean(elem.currentStyle[prop])) {
            $(elem)[prop == 'before' ? 'prepend' : 'append'](
                $(document.createElement('span')).addClass(prop).html(content)
            );
        }
    }

    $.pseudo = function(elem) {
        inject('before', elem);
        inject('after', elem);
        elem.runtimeStyle.behavior = null;
    };

    if(document.createStyleSheet) {
        var o = document.createStyleSheet(null, 0);
        o.addRule('.dummy','display: static;');
        o.cssText = 'html, head, head *, body, *.before, *.after, *.before *, *.after * { behavior: none; } * { behavior: expression($.pseudo(this)); }';
    }

})(jQuery);
```

I thought it might have something to do with having to change the `$` characters to `jQuery` since I am using WordPress and WP reserves the `$` character for prototype, but that didn't work either; it stopped the JS errors, but it still didn't work.

Comment: :after & :before work till IE8 & above

Comment: @sandeep My mistake, I was using the `not` selector with it which made it not work; but it's still not working for IE7.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @BillyMoat Updated the post with the URL.

Comment: @BillyMoat Didn't want the link up too long, so took it down. Think I'm gonna do a custom solution since this ain't working.

Comment: @Brett, please delete this question if you don't have an answer.

Comment: I think we should stop being worried for IE7 support. Google already did, why should we? http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9217279/Google_to_dump_support_for_Microsoft_s_IE7

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) (a JavaScript library to make MSIE behave like a standards-compliant browser)?

It will fix `:before`, `:after` and [many other issues](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) also supports the `:before` and `:after` psuedo elements in IE7 and many other browsers besides. From the [docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/):

> We support IE6+, Firefox 3.5+, Opera 9.6+, Safari 2+, Chrome. On mobile, we support iOS's mobile Safari, Android's WebKit browser, Opera Mobile, Firefox Mobile and whilst we’re still doing more testing we believe we support Blackberry 6+.